# Convert utf-8 string to cp950 encoding in python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm handling an encoding problem.
My input is a unicode string, such as:

```
>>> s
u'\xa6\xe8\xac\xc9'
```

Actually it is encoded in cp950. I want to decode it: (notice there's no "u")

```
>>> print unicode('\xa6\xe8\xac\xc9', 'cp950')
西界
```

However, I don't know how to get rid of that "u".
Direct conversion is not working:

```
>>> str(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The result of using encode() is not what I wanted:

```
>>> s.encode('utf8')
'\xc2\xa6\xc3\xa8\xc2\xac\xc3\x89'
```

what I want is `'\xa6\xe8\xac\xc9'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of an abuse of the `unicode` type. Characters in a `unicode` string are expected to be Unicode codepoints (e.g. `u'\u897f\u754c'`), and thus are encoding-agnostic. They are not supposed to be bytes from a specific encoding (Python 3 makes this distinction very clear by separating Unicode strings `str`, from byte strings `bytes`).

Since you want to just interpret each codepoint as bytes, you can do

```
u'\xa6\xe8\xac\xc9'.encode('iso-8859-1')
```

since the first 256 codepoints of Unicode are defined to be equal to the codepoints of ISO-8859-1. However, *please* try to fix the issue that gave you this incorrect Unicode string in the first place.

Comment: Actually I got the unicode string from an API which I cannot control.

Comment: Because it's already unicode, you can use `unicode_string.encode('cp950', errors='ignore')`

Answer (score 0):

So let's get this straight: you have a sequence of bytes that were read in as Unicode codepoints, and you need them to be interpreted as cp950 instead?

```
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in s)
'\xa6\xe8\xac\xc9'
>>> print ''.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in s).decode('cp950')
西界
```